# Create a new instance of an object and store it in an array

Tags: java, arrays, instance

This is a section of my code, i cannot figure out how to create a new transaction object with the values obtained from the file. The bold section of the code is the part i cannot seem to get around, thanks.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Account
{
// the customer
Customer customer;

// the account number
private String accountNumber;

// the account balance
private double balance;

// the account transactions
private Transaction transactions[];

// the number of account transactions
private int numberOfTransactions;

// constants
private static final int MAX_TRANSACTIONS = 10;
String FILENAME = "transactions.txt";


public Account(Customer customer, String accountNumber)
{
    this.customer = customer;
    this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
    balance = 0.0f;
    transactions = new Transaction[MAX_TRANSACTIONS];
    numberOfTransactions = 0;
}

public void readTransactions() {
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILENAME));
        String line = null;
        int count=0;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null && count < MAX_TRANSACTIONS) {
            String[] values = line.split(",");

             double amount = Double.parseDouble(values[0]);  // amount will be used in constructor of new Transaction
             String type = values[1];    // type will be used in constructor of new Transaction
             String reference = values[2];   // reference will be used in constructor of new Transaction

             String inputDate = "12/9/2003";
             SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("d/M/yyyy");
             Date date = null;
            try {
                date = formatter.parse(values[3]);  // date will be used in constructor of new Transaction
            }
            catch (ParseException exc)
            {
                System.out.println("A date format error occurred");
            }

            **for (int i= 0; i<MAX_TRANSACTIONS;i++)
             {   
                 transactions[i] = new Transaction (amount,type,reference,date);
             }** 



            count++;
        }
        br.close();

        numberOfTransactions = count;

        System.out.println("Transactions read from file successfully");

        updateBalance();    // calculates and updates the account balance
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
       System.out.println("A file error occurred");
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: Why do you initialize the array inside the loop? This way a new array is initialized each time you iterate. You should initialize the array `Transaction[] transactions = new Transaction [MAX_TRANSACTIONS];` before the `while` loop

Comment: You're not doing anything with the array except creating it and adding elements to it. What are you trying to achieve? What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: I'm trying to read the file transactions.txt and use the values from the file as the parameters and to create a new transactions object using these parameters? if that makes sense, I'm sorry as i said I only began using java a few weeks ago so I'm not sure as to whether I'm wording things correctly or not?  @JBNizet

Answer (score 0):

I think you're creating the Transaction obejct in a rigth way. However I think you need to take this line out of the while loop.

```
Transaction[] transactions = new Transaction [MAX_TRANSACTIONS];
```

Comment: thanks for the answers/comments, i have the line above at the beginning aswell, i just forgot and placed it in the loop also. the file FILENAME has 3 lines of values for type, reference, amount and date... but when the method is executed it is still displaying the objects in the array as null? I'm just new to java so I'm sorry if I'm not wording things correctly or explaining anything correctly.

Comment: can you update the question with you current code ? and where are you getting the null value

Comment: i think I've done so now, I'm getting null values when i inspect my Account object, the transactions should link to the newly created transactions? if that makes any sense

Comment: I don't understand where are you getting the error. Can you add the code where the error is thrown?